# image view in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, uiimageview, imageview

hello i searched a lot for a solution but nothing worked for me

```
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Image image = new Image(IMG_PATH);
    photoAdmin.setImage(image);}
```

here's the IMG_PATH

```
    public static final String IMG_PATH = "C:\\Users\\ibeno\\Documents\\GitHub\\PiDev\\PiDev\\Images\\11880660_447255635481530_1415231414421167737_n.jpg";
```

and i declared photoAdmin as an ImageView but still got this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
```

Answer (score -1):

`c` is interpreted as the `URL` protocol.

Add [`file://`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to your Path to fix it:

```java
public static final String IMG_PATH = "file:///C:/Users/ibeno/Documents/GitHub/PiDev/PiDev/Images/11880660_447255635481530_1415231414421167737_n.jpg"";
```

But as mentioned by @James_D, this is not a very clever solution since we hardcode the value of the URL, the better way to do this would be through the `Paths` API:

```java
final String IMG_PATH = "C:\\Users\\ibeno\\Documents\\GitHub\\PiDev\\PiDev\\Images\\11880660_447255635481530_1415231414421167737_n.jpg";
String pathUrl = Paths.get(IMG_PATH).toUri().toURL().toString();
Image image = new Image(pathUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked 
When i open the page i want to show the image of current user
The nameof the photo is saved in the database but when i put (IMG_PATH+ a.getPhoto); it won't show anything

Comment: I am glad it worked, please upvote and accept the answer if it helped. How are you saving the Photo in your DB. As the name of the Photo? I would suggest asking another question and putting all the details there, I will try to help you there.

Comment: This is not really a robust solution though. Images are typically resources and should be bundled as part of the application. This solution will fail if the application is run on another machine, and especially another platform. URLs should never be constructed by hand like this; if you really want to read an image from the filesystem (rather than a resource), use the ~file` or `Path` API to construct the URL.

Comment: @James_D thank you for the comment, I updated the answer with your suggestions.